# C# with Xamarin: Check if a message was sent on Whatsapp

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.forms

I'm sending a image on Whatsapp with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetAction(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView);
                intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, shareBytes);
                intent.SetType("image/*");
                intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(""),"image/*");
                var intentChooser = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Sharing Image");
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intentChooser);
```

So I need some confirmation that the message was successfully sent to do something. How can I receive this confirmation?

PS: I can use C# or Java code because I'm using Xamarin Forms, any solution for any of these languages are welcome.

Comment: You can never know for sure if the message was successfully sent this way. Why do you want to know?

Comment: If the message was successfully sent, I can finish some function. If not, I need to send some info to my server.

Comment: There seems to be no way to monitor the results this way.